# Use AppId to uninstall program installed with Inno Setup in case uninstaller exe is lost

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I am trying to changing our software installer (set up) project from using Wix to Inno Setup.

In Wix, it has `msiexec /X {appId}` as `UninstallString`. But I notice Inno Setup does it differently. It calls `unins000.exe` straight away. What I concern is that if in any cases, `unins000.exe` is missing from the program folder, then user might not be able to uninstall our software properly.

My questions are:

- Are there any ways I can customize the `UninstallString` to be using `AppId` to uninstall?
- Can I use the `AppId` to implement uninstallation with Inno Setup?
  (*I have static `AppId` for our software so `AppId` is always known.)

I have tried to manually type in the command `msiexec /X {AppID}_isl` in command prompt but seems cannot uninstall the software this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the uninstaller executable gets deleted, then you can't uninstall the program. The fix in that case would be to reinstall the program to recreate the uninstaller executable, then uninstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup does not use MSI database at all. Inno Setup is completely standalone, without any dependencies or global databases or registrations of any kind.

Inno Setup AppId is not MSI product code. You can in a sense, uninstall the application using the AppId. By looking up the AppId in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and using the `UninstallString` therein. But that's obviously not what you want.

Using Inno Setup's own uninstaller is the only way to uninstall the application.

*I do not think you are solving a real problem. Whatever user changes in the installation folder would somehow damage the application. The user is not supposed to touch the installation folder any way. And by default the user does not even have permissions to do so (if you are installing your application to `Program Files`).*

---

Anyway, reinstalling the application (and thus recreating the uninstaller) will for many cases solve the problem of a missing uninstaller.

Comment: Hi pimpo, thanks for the quick respond. I agree with the idea the users should never touch the ProgramFolders. I was just thinking some edge cases and see if there any workaround or maybe a trusted way i can avoid them happening. Thanks for your advice though.